# Automating Quartz Scheduled Job in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, scheduler

I am able to schedule a program in Java using Quartz 2 Scheduler. I need to start that scheduler program whenever the Apache Server starts up. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You can just use plain Java class with a static initializer block to initialize your Quartz timer. If you want to do it in JavaEE way, then you can either use EJB3.x or Servlets.

Example using EJB3.x Singleton-

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class QuartzTimerBean{
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
            ...
            // Start Quartz timer here
            ...
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void cleanup(){
            ...
            // Clean up Quartz timer
            ...
    }
}
```

Example of using ServletContextListener

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class QuartzTimerListener implements ServletContextListener{

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
            ...
            // Start Quartz timer here
            ...
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
            ...
            // Clean up Quartz timer
            ...
}
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app ...>
   <listener>
       <listener-class><fully qualified path>.QuartzTimerListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: How do I automate it? Should I add the Java class name in any configuration file? I want the program to start whenever the server starts and end whenever it shuts down.

Comment: You can do this automatically with Singletons. But if you are using ServletContextListener, then use the above <listener> xml snippet in web.xml.